# CreateMonitoredItems: Request unsupported DataEncoding [OPC UA CTT]

Tags: .net, opc-ua

I'm trying to fix errors with CTT software provided by OPC UA Foundation and I'm stuck with this error: `Expected: BadDataEncodingUnsupported, but received: BadDataEncodingInvalid (0x80380000)`

1. This test can run selecting `Server Category > ComplexType 2017 Server Facet > Attribute Alternate Encoding`
2. Run the selected test, and see result of test `Err-004.js`

**What I tried**

- Search on web
- Search docs on OPC
- Change config OPC Server
- Search on other repos

**What I am expecting**

- Test works

Comment: I think your best chance is contact the developer or raise a issue on their repro. Don't think you will find someone on SO which has a solution to this problem.